# How to get magnitude of signals in Verilog

Tags: verilog

I have a module `Magnitude`:

```
module Magnitude(
  input [31:0] re,
  input [31:0] im,
  output [31:0] out
);
  assign out = re * re + im * im;
endmodule
```

Now, for 128 signals, I need to find out the magnitude. That is, I need a way to count up to 128. How can I do that?

Also, this is the very first Verilog code I wrote. Any advice on making it efficient is welcome.

Comment: Can you be more clear with the problem statement? Are you trying to say that you want to do the above operation for 128 different signals?

Comment: `re` and `im` signals are coming continuously. I need that for first 128 pairs, find `out` and reset. Next do for 128 pairs so on.

Comment: Do you intend to keep on accumulating **out** value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my understanding of your question, may be you intend to do the following:

```
module Magnitude(
  input [31:0] re,
  input clk;
  input reset;
  input [31:0] im,
  output reg [31:0] out
);

reg [6:0] counter;

 always @(posedge clk or negedge reset)
 begin
  if(!reset)
   begin
   counter<=0;
   end
  else 
    begin
     if (counter==7'd128)
       counter<=0;
     else
       counter<=counter+1;
    end
 end

 always @(posedge clk or negedge reset)
 begin
   if(!reset)
     out<=0;
   else 
    begin
     if (counter==7'd127)
       out<=0;            // As soon as counter counts to 128, it will become zero.
     else
       out <= out + re * re + im * im;
    end
 end
endmodule
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I intended to have. However, don't you need  to take `clk` or `reset` as input?

Comment: You can use posedge also for reset. It just indicates active high or active low. If you write "posedge reset", in the always block you need to write as " if (reset) " instead of  "if (!reset)".

Comment: If you put both clock and reset in the sensitive list, the reset need no wait for next posedge of clk i.e. reset is asynchronous to clock.

Comment: OK. Thank you again for explanation.

Comment: @ssgr A few notes on your code: You never declare `counter`, which you should like so `reg [31:0] counter`. You need to make `out` a `reg` type, `output reg [31:0] out`. `counter` need only be 7-bits and you can just utilize overflow to set `counter` back to zero if you like (`counter` would wrap to zero at `7'd127` as `7'd127 + 7'd1` is `7'd0` in 7-bits). Need to use NBA on the assign of `out` (`out <= out + re * re + im * im;`). As you do not have any reset logic in your second block, you should remove sensitivity to `reset` or add a reset case.

Comment: There are still a few typos, e.g. `;` in 3rd and 4th line; `reg` in 6th line. Also, we need a register before we assign it to `out` (e.g. `reg [31:0] temp;` .... `temp <= re * re + im * im;` ... `assign out = temp;` which I could fix myself. Anyway, thanks for your help. :-)